# Why does webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); cause the screen to go blank?

Tags: android, webview, webchromeclient

My app uses a WebView.  When I have `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` set, the screen appears blank on a Galaxy S9, but NOT on Galaxy Note 8 or Pixel 3a.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this line before setting the client

```
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Sometimes you might need to enable Dom like

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Its easier to find the problem if you post your source code.